# setFramerateLimit() function not working in sfml

Tags: c++, sfml, frame-rate

I am trying learn SFML and I want to limit the frame rate . here is my code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp

int main()
{
    sf::Window win (sf::VideoMode(200,200),"SDSDefgwre");
    sf::Clock clock;
    win.setFramerateLimit(30);

    sf::Time t;
    while(win.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event e;
        clock.restart().asSeconds();
        while(win.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if(e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                win.close();
        }    
        t = clock.getElapsedTime();    
        std::cout << 1.f/t.asSeconds() <<'\n';    
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Where I run this code I get 200000 FPS. which means

```
    win.setFramerateLimit(60);
```

is not working. Please tell me where am going wrong ?

Comment: I think you should get 0 fps with this code because you are not rendering anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `setFrameLimit`:

> If a limit is set, the window will use a small delay after each call
>   to `display()` to ensure that the current frame lasted long enough to
>   match the framerate limit.

You do not render anything, and you never actually swap the draw buffers (which is what the call to `win.display()` would do).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not calling

```
win.display()
```

Because the window waits for the frame in the display function.

Your code should look something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window win(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SDSDefgwre");
    sf::Clock clock;
    win.setFramerateLimit(30);

sf::Time t;
while (win.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event e;
    clock.restart().asSeconds();
    while (win.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            win.close();
    }
    win.display();
    t = clock.getElapsedTime();
    std::cout << 1.0 / t.asSeconds() << '\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is also a problem with calculation of the elapsed time (`t`) itself. The clock should be read and restarted at the same time; hence the line with `clock.restart()` should be removed, and the line after the `display()` call should be amended to `t = clock.restart();`. In the above function the difference is probably neglegible, though.